# Undefined property: Illuminate\Validation\Validator::$errors in laravel

Tags: laravel

Undefined property: Illuminate\Validation\Validator::$errors in laravel

here is my controller file how to solve it i think here  problem is any namespace where is it i do not know please guide me

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route; 
use Input; 
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect; 
use Illuminate\Http\Request;  
use App\models\Designation; 
use Validator;  
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response; 
class Cdesigination extends Controller
{
   public $flight;
    public function __construct(){
        $this->flight = new Designation; 
    }
    public function index()
    {   
      return view('designation');
     }  
    public function techer(Request $request) {
          $Validator =Validator::make(array(
        'name'=>Input::get('name'),
         'detail'=>Input::get('detail')
      ),array(
        'name'             => 'required',            
        'detail'            => 'required'
    ));
        if ($Validator->fails()) { 
            return Response::json([
                'success'=>false,
                'error' =>$Validator->errors->toArray()
            ]);

    }
    else{

        $this->flight->name = $request->name;
        $this->flight->detail = $request->detail; 
        $this->flight->save();
         return Response::json([
                'success'=>true]); 
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$Validator->errors()->toArray()
```

Errors() is function, so the braces are important

Comment: It Works. Thanks.